# How to drop a pandas group based on a condition from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes, that look like this

```
df1 =
   name   color
0  John   Blue
1  John   Red
2  Lucy   Green
3  Lucy   Blue
4  Max    Blue
2  Max    White
```

And

```
df2 =
   name   value
0  John   15
1  Lucy   20
2  Max    5
```

I am trying to drop all the grouped names in `df1` whose `value` in `df2` is **below 10** (in this case, I would want to drop all the rows with `df1['name']='Max'`).

The result I am trying to get is:

```
df1 =
   name   color
0  John   Blue
1  John   Red
2  Lucy   Green
3  Lucy   Blue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [731]: res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name')
In [736]: res[res['value'].ge(10)][['name','color']]

Out[736]: 
   name  color
0  John   Blue
1  John    Red
2  Lucy  Green
3  Lucy   Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#get names that are greater than or equal to 10
filtr = df2.loc[df2.value.ge(10),'name']

#extract names that match filtr

df1.loc[df1.name.isin(filtr)]

    name    color
0   John    Blue
1   John    Red
2   Lucy    Green
3   Lucy    Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['name'].isin(['Max']) # select the df1 which name is 'Max'

df1=df1[~df1['name'].isin(['Max'])] # reverse select the other elements.
```